# How to compare two values from two lists in Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I'm trying to compare two values, one from `list1` and another from `list2`. Each value is stored in dictionaries in these lists.

The data is being read in from csv files.

Currently my code is comparing only the first value and not iterating:

```
import csv    

list1 = []
list2 = []

reader1 = csv.DictReader(open('file1.csv'))
reader2 = csv.DictReader(open('file2.csv'))

list1 = [x for x in reader1]
list2 = [x for x in reader2]

print [x['MyMail'] for x in list1 for y in list2 if x['MyMail']==y['Email']]
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to do, but in general when you want your list comprehension to iterate over two lists in parallel, you should do `[some_expression_goes_here for a,b in zip(list1, list2)]`

Comment: Are you sure about the syntax in your last line ? This throws a `SyntaxError` near `list1 y`

Comment: I just want to mention that list comprehensions shouldn't be used just because it's fancy but to make code more readable and organized, they are not faster than a normal for loop. If they get too messy it's probably a good idea to just use a regular for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `set` for this.

```
s1 = set([i['MyMail'].lower() for i in reader1 if i['MyMail']])
s2 = set([i['Email'].lower() for i in reader2 if i['Email']])

common_emails = s1 & s2
```